# What is the name of this valve from my sprinkler system?

Tags: valve, sprinkler-system

This small release valve was broken on my sprinkler system and I want to get a replacement. What is the name of this valve?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://www.sprinklerwarehouse.com/universal-tc-lead-free-male-x-female-with-test-cock-1-8-in-x-1-8-in-mpt-tc-1818m (that said, plumbing standards are complicated... you might have different ends)

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a shot.

Comment: So, @AloysiusDefenestrate, it's a Test Cock?   Don't you want the joy of writing that answer?

Comment: I’d upvote you @jay613